Fundamental group of $S^n$
I begin to learn algebraic topology from J. R. Munkres. Topology (Second Edition) (Upper Saddle River: Prentice Hall, 2000) There is generel theorem for calculating fundamental groups of some spaces with covering spaces in page 346 of this book:
*Theorem 54.6. Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a covering map; let $p\left(e_{0}\right)=b_{0}$.
(a) The homomorphism $p_{*}: \pi_{1}\left(E, e_{0}\right) \rightarrow \pi_{1}\left(B, b_{0}\right)$ is a monomorphism.
(b) Let $H=p_{*}\left(\pi_{1}\left(E, e_{0}\right)\right)$. The lifting correspondence $\phi$ induces an injective map
$$
\Phi: \pi_{1}\left(B, b_{0}\right) / H \rightarrow p^{-1}\left(b_{0}\right)
$$
of the collection of right cosets of $H$ into $p^{-1}\left(b_{0}\right)$, which is bijective if $E$ is path connected.
(c) If $f$ is a loop in $B$ based at $b_{0}$, then $[f] \in H$ if and only if $f$ lifts to a loop in $E$ based at $e_{0}$.
I can prove that the fundamental group of the torus is isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by using this theorem, but I could not prove $\pi_{1}\left( S^n\right)$
is isomorphic to the trivial group. Is it possible to do this with this theorem? I appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

No, it's not. You need something else for that, like van Kampen or something.

You mean $n>1$, of course. You need to know $S^n$ is simply connected to know that it is its own only connected covering space.

the usual way to prove this is  via some version of approximation: show that any map $S^1 \to S^n$ ($n>1$) is (based) homotopic to a nonsurjective map  and use that $S^n \setminus {p}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, which is contractible. There are a lot of flavors such as simplicial, smooth, or CW approximation.

...or, perhaps even more "usual", by a straightforward application of van Kampen's theorem.
